# validate function for special characters for prescribed data in url in php , CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

http://localhost/sssss/sss.php&send=90&msg=z a data c
guys i need to validate for the particular data which is in the url... validate function should be able to check for special characters only for that data ... how to achieve this....
 i need to validate in such a manner that no special characters will be in included along with the data.... and the url is how we use for recharging so spaces everything will be included

Comment: can you write down the url without separating? spaces?

Comment: used for recharging amount.... where 100 is the amount... i need to validate in such a manner that no special characters will be in included along with the amount....

Comment: @gkaykck... its how we use the url..... used for recharging purpose

Comment: localhost/xxxxxxx/xxxrecharge.php?send=1234567891&msg=L A xxx16666661 100 C, this doesn't seems like a valid url? Is your url localhost/xxxxxxx/xxxrecharge.php?send=1234567891&msg=LAxxx16666661100C ?

Comment: yup its my localhost..... just testing it....

Comment: there is difference between 2 url's i wrote in the comment. Former has SPACES(blanks) IN URL, latter hasn't. And spaces in url doesn't seem right to me

Comment: this url is valid and it works fine for recharging ... just need to know how to validate for just amount in this url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$msg = $_GET['msg'];
list(,,,$amount,) = explode(" ", $msg);
if(preg_match("/^\\d+$/", $amount))
  echo "valid amount!";
else
  echo "invalid amount";
```

Hope this helps. Cheers